# Quicksort for string array

Tags: c++, string, quicksort

After looking through articles, tutorials and solutions everywhere, i haven't come across anything that explains how to use quicksort for string arrays. All examples I found are of either "int" or "char".

This is my edited code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>



using namespace std;

int count;
template <class T>
void printArray(T ar[], int sz);
template <class T>
void bubbleSort(T ar[], int sz);
void quickSortMain(string items[], int ct);
void quickSort(string items[], int left, int right);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Function Implementation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    int numOfData = 50000;
    string line, temp;
    ofstream resultFile;
    ofstream tableFile;
    double data[100][2];
    string patient[numOfData];
    ifstream dataFile("shufflePatient.txt");
    int i;
    int SIZE = 0;

    cout << "Program to shuffle data" << endl << endl;
    cout << "This program will calculate swapping processes and running time.";


    /*Storing data*/
    cout << "Reading data in process.." << endl;
    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        i=-1;
        while (dataFile.good()) {
            getline (dataFile, line);
            if (i>=0) patient[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }

    SIZE = 5;
    quickSortMain(patient, 5);


    /*Writing to file*/
    cout << "Writing to file.." << endl;
    resultFile.open ("test.txt");
    for (int i=0 ; i<numOfData ; i++) {
        resultFile << patient[i] << "\n";
    }
    resultFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void quickSortMain(string items[], int ct)
{
  quickSort(items, 0, ct-1);
}


void quickSort(string items[], int left, int right)
{
  int i, j;
  char *x;
  string temp[10];

  i = left;
  j = right;
  x = items[(left+right)/2];

  do {
    while((strcmp(items[i],x) < 0) && (i < right)) {
       i++;
    }
    while((strcmp(items[j],x) > 0) && (j > left)) {
        j--;
    }
    if(i <= j) {
      strcpy(temp, items[i]);
      strcpy(items[i], items[j]);
      strcpy(items[j], temp);
      i++;
      j--;
   }
  } while(i <= j);

  if(left < j) {
     quickSort(items, left, j);
  }
  if(i < right) {
     quickSort(items, i, right);
  }
}









//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// prints array of size size
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void printArray(T patient[], int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << patient[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}




//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sorts array of size size by Bubble Sort method
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void bubbleSort(T patient[], int size) //returning an int
{
    bool noChange = true;
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
    noChange = true;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      if(patient[j] < patient[j - 1])
      {
        swap(patient[j], patient[j-1]);
        count = count + 1;
        noChange = false;
      }
    }
    if (noChange)
      return ;
  }
}
```

The error i got was in this line:

```
 x = items[(left+right)/2];
```

I changed

`char x*;`  to `string x;`

I don't know if that was correct. Now the error im getting is that `strcmp` and `strcpy` are not declared. Any help on what i should do next?

Comment: @ Zeta:
still stuck. any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
string patient[numOfData];
```

vs.

```
template <class T>
void quickSortMain(char items[][10], int ct)
```

vs.

```
quickSortMain(patient, 5);
```

`quickSortMain` expects an array of `char[10]`, not `string[]`. Not only this, but it also depends on a template parameter. Drop the `template <class T>` and replace `char[][10]` with `string[]`.

Comment: my assignment requires me to use bubble sort, quick sort and heap sort. im done with bubble sort. working on quick sort right now.

if changing quickSortMain to use string[] wont help me, what should i do? keeping in mind i have to use string and not 'int' or 'char'

Comment: @user2959974: Oh, well, you can change it to `string[]`. I was thinking in terms of reusabilty, not in terms of assignments. But don't mix `std::string` with `strcmp` and other things.

Comment: i changed all the "char items[][10]" to "string items[]"

still no change, the error keeps coming.

Comment: @user2959974: Missed the template line.

Comment: Done! The error is gone, but a new one has come up. Now i get an error in this line:

x = items[(left+right)/2];

it says i cannot convert string to char. i understand that. x has been assigned as a 'char'. what should i do?

also, there is another error. strcmp and strcpy weren't declared. i think that means i have to use some other method.

Comment: @user2959974: You're mixing C++ and C. Note that there are `operator<` and `operator>` for strings.